# Restangular does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, tastypie, restangular

Restangular's lack of documentation is killing me.
I am trying to consume a REST endpoint. I'm using Django-Tastypie as the backend provider.

```
var baseQuestions = Restangular.all('questions');
baseQuestions.one($routeParams.questionId).get().then(function(question) {
    console.log(question);
});
```

And in my AngularJS app config function, I've made sure I set Restangular the correct way.

```
RestangularProvider.setBaseUrl('/api/v1');
RestangularProvider.setRequestSuffix('?format=json');
RestangularProvider.setResponseExtractor(function(response, operation, what, url) {
    var newResponse;
    if (operation === 'getList') {
        newResponse = response.objects;
        newResponse.metadata = response.meta;
    } else {
        newResponse = response.data;
    }
    return newResponse;
});
```

But the printed console value shows question is undefined, obviously I don't want that, I need the actual data.

The REST endpoint works fine in the browser.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you `console.log(response, operation)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when using Restangular to call for a unique element, I suggest doing it like this:

```
Restangular.one('questions', $routeParams.questionId).get().then(
    function(question) {
        console.log(question);
    });
```

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: This may sound crazy, but it just started working today... I'm not sure what I've changed, I'll look through the Git commits. Thanks for replying.